# Take snapshots from all the frames in a video tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using my webcam to take screenshots from all the frames after pressing a button and store all of them in a folder. Is there any solution to solve this problem?

```
function takepicture() {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (width && height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    photo.setAttribute('src', data);
  } else {
    clearphoto();
  }
}
```

this function only can take the screenshot from the current frame but I want to store all the frames.

Comment: You'll probably need a different function since what you want to do is nothing like what your code is doing

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. First I wanted to record a video but most of the APIs don't work in ios and Mac. Now I am trying to save this video as a bunch of images.